# Каким образом отслеживать правильное написание имен переменных?

Tags: python

Создал Flask–проект, в котором есть следующая модель

```
class SiteComment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'site_comment'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    verified_user_id = Column(BigInteger) 
    ...

    def __init__(self, params):
        ...
        self.verified_user = params.get('verified_user', -1)
        ...
```

Как вы видите, я допустил опечатку в методе `__init__`, где инициализировал `verified_user` вместо `verified_user_id`. Ошибки во время исполнения никакой нет. Спустя несколько недель, добавляя реализацию резервной выгрузки данных из базы заметил, что соответствующее поле пустое.

Такие ошибки у меня происходят время от времени и найти их крайне сложно. Пожалуйста, подскажите, каким образом сделать так, чтобы как можно быстрее обнаружить подобные ошибки?

Понятно, что можно у базы создавать не нулевые поля, на какие–то методы покрыть тестами и тд, но весь код тестами не покроешь, а опечатка может быть везде (использую редактор nano, автоподстановки нет). В компилируемых языках вроде C++, подобные ошибки найдет компилятор или линковщик. Есть ли что–то в python, что поможет быть более уверенным в коде?

Comment: Интерпретатор действительно не может знать, имели в виду ``verified_user_id`` или действительно создали новую переменную ``verified_user``. Так что или редактор с автоподстановкой или ИДЕ, которая будет подсвечивать созданные, но не используемые переменные.

Comment: @Эникейщик Мне кажется, есть (1) какая–то методология для этого и (2) автоматические инструменты, которые могут находить подобные ошибки (вполне логично предполагать, что если две переменные одного класса различаются в несколько символов, есть вероятность, что это опечатка). Хотелось бы про это все узнать подробно.

Comment: На хабре была статья про скрипт для поиска полей с опечаткой

Comment: для примера с бд, можно "not null" добавить ограничение. Иногда, можно `__slots__` выставить (или использовать классы, которые за вас это делают). Для вашего примера можно автоматически проверять атрибуты (`__setattr__` и как именно зависит как `db.Model` реализована). В общем случае, следует тестировать важную для вас функциональность автоматически. Проверки типов в С++ это всего лишь один и не самый важный тип тестов (все ошибки вы так никогда не поймаете -- можно во время компиляции многие вычисления делать, но это часто не удобно, не нужно и не достаточно)...

Comment: ... У вас уже есть читаемый Turing-complete язык (Питон), который любые ограничения может выразить (для частных случаев, можно декларативную разметку использовать, чтобы автоматически некоторые типы тестов генерировать, к примеру, type annotations + mypy).

Comment: @jfs Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, пояснить, что и как мне следует сделать (попробовать) в каждом из подходов, чтобы оценить эффективность каждого из подходов?

Comment: @gil9red Буду крайне признателен за развернутый ответ за вашим авторством со ссылкой на Хабр!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, все-таки нашел: https://habrahabr.ru/post/249423/ В статье подробно написано, и мб это поможет в вашем примере

Comment: в общем случае все подходы какие-то только есть можно использовать (вплоть до [формальных доказательств](http://www.envisage-project.eu/proving-android-java-and-python-sorting-algorithm-is-broken-and-how-to-fix-it/)), в частном случае считайте, что если вы не попробовали фактически выполнить резервное копирование *и* восстановление с последующими тестами, то у вас нет резервного копирования

Comment: Представьте, что при вычислении рейтинга чего-нибудь вы плюс с минусом перепутали. Как вы подобную ошибку заметите? Написав тест, проверяющий рейтинг. Что если формула у вас вообще неправильная (не во всех нужных случаях результат с достаточной точностью выдаёт)? Как вы это заметите? Написав тесты, который покрывают нужные типы ввода. Иначе говоря, я бы не стал заморачиваться с исправлением опечаток (если у вас не миллион этих таблиц), а писал бы тесты, проверяющие вашу функциональность напрямую (это поймает и опечатки, и арифметические ошибки и ошибки в выбранной модели для формулы итд).

Answer (score 1):

Это наверняка костыль и вполне возможно, что есть более изящные решения, но я не очень разбираюсь в Тьюринг-полноте, формальных доказательствах и этом всём. Эта примесь просто проверяет при присваивании, что атрибут определён в классе:

```
class AttributeValidatingMixin:
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if hasattr(self.__class__, attr):
           object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError('Нет такого атрибута!')


class SiteComment(db.Model, AttributeValidatingMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'site_comment'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    verified_user_id = Column(BigInteger) 
    ...

    def __init__(self, params):
        ...
        self.verified_user = params.get('verified_user', -1)
        ...
```

Конкретно с SQLAlchemy не проверял, но тоже должно работать.